# Does the isSelect-method of QSqlQuery return true when a stored procedure is executed?

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Will the isSelect-method of QSqlQuery return true when a stored procedure containing a SELECT-statment is executed on sqlserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states that isSelect: "Returns true if the current query is a SELECT statement; otherwise returns false"

During my testing I found that it also returns true for an EXEC statement on sqlserver if there is a result-set to be fetched.

Comment: not always unfortunately... got some trouble with sybase and TDS